# Different connection string in application.properties set by ci yaml file

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, gitlab

I am trying to figure out the cleanest/simplest way to set my connection string in an application.properties file in my spring boot app from our ci/pipeline.  We are using gitlab.  We are deploying two instances of our services, etc.  I also have little/no yaml experience.

So the current application.properties has a value/property:
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://.........

Our .gitlab-ci.yml looks something like this:

```
cache:
  untracked: true
build:
  stage: build
  script: "mvn install -B -DskipTests"
  artifacts:
    paths: 
    - target/*.jar
test:
  script: "mvn test -B"
integration-test:
  script: "mvn failsafe:integration-test failsafe:verify -B"
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - scp target/*.jar server:~/deployments/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.jar
    - ssh -t -t server "sudo systemctl restart ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}"
  environment:
    name: test
  only:
  - master

deploy_demo:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - "docker build -t server:5000/service ."
    - "docker push server:5000/service"
    - "ssh server 'docker-compose pull service'"
    - "ssh server 'docker-compose up -d service'"
  environment:
    name: test
  when: manual
  only:
  - master
```

I've read some options like adding profiles, etc.  I'm just looking for the easiest way to have the default build use one connection string and the deploy_demo job use another.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: profile is probably the easiest way to do this when you have many settings that change per environment. or on the CI server you run the app with option -Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb:://qa-db.com...... or set environment var for that on the server you deploy too.

Comment: mavriksc, ok.  that makes sense.  wanted to make sure I wasn't missing an easy option.  thanks for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to leave this open, I choose to create two profiles and in the build command set spring.profiles.active=demo for the one build and just used default for the other.  Thanks mavriksc, for the info